# Format opencart select option value

Tags: php, opencart, string-formatting

I have the option named artwork which has 3 values (We Design Single, We Design Double, Upload Artwork).

I want to edit the view product.tbl to format the "We Design Single" and "We Design Double" So it only shows as "We Design".

I think this is the part of the code i need to edit but unsure how

```
<div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
    <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
    <span class="required">*</span>
    <?php } ?>
    <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
    <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]">
         <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
         <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>">      
         ?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
        (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><span id="newPrice"><?php echo
         $option_value['price']; ?></span>)
        <?php } ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
   </select>
</div>
```

I think you would use an if statement to determine if the 'product_option_value_id' == 'We Design Single' || 'product_option_value_id'=='We Design Single' then use substr() to display only part of 'product_option_value_id'.

Any Ideas?

Comment: So You want to have these entries in the selectbox: *We Design*, *We Design* and *Upload Artwork*? If not and only two should be there: *We Design* and *Upload Artwork* - why not deleting the the *We Design Double* option and renaming the *We Design Single* to *We Design*???

Comment: Because the option is dependant on another option and the prices of the two 'We Design Single' and 'We Design Double are different

Comment: The problem is they have to be unique keys but I don't want the customer to see the single and double part of the string

Comment: The customer before selecting We design or upload has to choose wether they want single or double sided which determines which options they will see in the artwork select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if ($option_value['name'] == 'We Design Single' || $option_value['name'] == 'We Design Double') { ?>

 <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo "We Design" ?>
  <?php } else { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo       $option_value['name']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Got it working anyway